# How to calculate the properties of spiral antena?

Tags: antenna, microwave

I noticed some articles about analysis of Archimedean spiral antena. My understanding is that the antena of such type is a compact one and it  allows broadband performance.

To be more precise I'd like to understand pros and cons of the spiral antena defined by eq. in polar coordinates \$r'^2+r^2=t^2\$.
The spiral is very similar to Archimedean one at large \$t\$ and it is similar to Galileo spiral at small \$t\$.

You can see the picture at [mathcurve](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/gaichenkov/gaichenkov.shtml) web-site.
What would be advantages and disadvantages of the antena? Any possible application for such spiral in electrical engineering?
Please note this is my personal interest/hobby like DIY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest (and quite possibly only tractable) answer to your question can be found through simulation: For some antenna shapes, we can analytically calculate (i.e. we have formulas) what the fields look like, but in general, and especially in the case of things defined like yours, it's unlikely we find something analytically solvable.

That means that to figure out what the radiation pattern, impedance and phase pattern of this antenna looks like, you'd have to use an EM simulator. OpenEMS would be a free example. You'll probably get results faster if you know someone who has access to CST studio and experience using it.

I don't think anyone could look at this formula and tell you any advantages or disadvantages directly. Chances are it performs worse in most aspect than "established" wideband antenna types: over the last 50 years, many people have tried many antenna types, and if there's no evidence in literature your proposed antenna works well, then it probably doesn't.